# How to remove folder path within zip file.I want only txt files in zip file

Tags: asp.net

I am created the zip file in this path "D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi.zip". But within this Hi.zip file creating the folders "D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi" after that added 2 txt files showing....So I need to remove folder path in zip file ...I am using following code and sharpziplib library...thanks in advance.

```
*enter code here*
StartZip("D:/Nagaraj/Dotnet/Zipfile/Zipfile/Filebuild/Hi/", Server.MapPath("Filebuild/Hi.zip"));

public void StartZip(string directory, string zipFileName)
{
    ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(zipFileName);
    z.BeginUpdate();
    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

    foreach (string filename in filenames)
      {
        z.Add(filename);
        string s = Path.GetFileName(filename);
      }
      z.CommitUpdate();
      z.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code, you can remove the folder path:

```
FileInfo hfinfo = null;
hfinfo = new FileInfo(HFileName.ToString());
if (!hfinfo.Exists) {
    hfinfo.Create();
}
HGetTData.ToString().TrimEnd();

sw.Write(HGetTData.ToString());
HGetTData.Length = 0;

sw.Flush();

sw.Close();
sw.Dispose();

z.NameTransform = new ZipNameTransform(hosttmppath);
z.BeginUpdate();
z.Add(HFileName.ToString(), fname[i] + ".txt");
z.CommitUpdate();

FileInfo theFile = new FileInfo(HFileName.ToString());
if (theFile.Exists) {
    File.Delete(HFileName.ToString());
}
```